# Swift - call function without initializing the controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I'm stuck on something simple & complicated for me at the same time.

I'm creating an app using Swift that works with SocketRocket and WebSockets, once a simple ViewController (`class myVC`) is loaded, within the `viewDidLoad()` I call a function, send the message to the server and get the response back. All this works fine.

I parse the response in another class (`class dataParsing`) and then want to call a function from the ViewController that is still on top and show the answer using a function: `presentData(data)`

If I use: `myVC().presentData(data)` the entire ViewController reloads and the message is sent as the viewcontroller is re-initialised and we go in an endless loop...

What is the solution?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call a method of a view controller (and more generally of an instance of a class/struct) you need the instance - creating a new instance as you do with `myCV().presentData(data)` creates a new instance which has no relationship with the one originating the request.

A possible way is to pass the view controller instance to your data parsing class - then simply invoke the target method on that instance.

A better way is to pass a closure to the data parser, which simply calls the `presentData()` method - the closure is then executed by the data parser.

Another solution could be to use notifications: you define a certain event, make the view controller listen for that event, and let the data parser trigger it when the right conditions are met.

Last, and probably the easiest one, but I don't know how much feasible - depending on how the interaction between the view controller and the data parser is. I presume that at the end of the network operation you create and invoke a method of the data parser, which is performed synchronously. If that is correct, rather than invoking a view controller method from the data parser, simply invoke it directly from the view controller after the data parser method returns.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio! I don't seem to be able to find a way to pass the VC instance so I will work on the notifications using Notification Center or as you say the other way is to change the 'path' and once the message is received to begin the process from the VC. Very useful advise!